# Conditional disabling of widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

In the following code, I have been trying to disable the entry1 widget every time I select 1 in the combobox and disable entry2 when i select 2 in combobox.

this is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def refresh():
    if v.get() == 'A':
        entry1.state(['disabled'])
        entry2.state(['!disabled'])
    elif v.get() == 'B':
        entry2.state(['disabled'])
        entry1.state(['!disabled'])




root = Tk()
v = StringVar()
var = StringVar()

entry1 = ttk.Entry (root, textvariable= var)
entry1.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=(E,W))

entry2 = ttk.Entry (root, textvariable= var)
entry2.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=(E,W))


v_list=['A','B']
v.set(v_list[1])
v_optionmenu = apply(OptionMenu, (root,v) + tuple(v_list))
v_optionmenu.grid(column=4,row=11,sticky=(W,E))

var = v
root.bind('<Return>', lambda e: refresh)

root.mainloop()
```

I wanted to create condition based enabling and disabling of widgets.
My conditions usually are:

> selection in combobox
>   Selection of radiobutton

Please Advice how i can go about it.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, where do you declare de vfault option? If you could post your entire code or a link to it on the web it would be helpful.

Comment: @dex19dt I am sorry for the error. Have corrected now.
Thanks for pointing it out, may have confused others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def refresh(*args):

    if  v.get() == 'Disable' :
        fb_entry.state(['disabled'])
        fw_entry.state(['disabled'])
        fb.set('')
        fw.set('')
    elif v.get() == 'Enable' :
        fb_entry.state(['!disabled'])
        fw_entry.state(['!disabled'])


root = Tk()
v = StringVar()
var = StringVar()

entry1 = ttk.Entry (root, textvariable= var)
entry1.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=(E,W))

entry2 = ttk.Entry (root, textvariable= var)
entry2.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=(E,W))


v_list=['Disable','Enable']
v.set(v_list[1])
v_optionmenu = apply(OptionMenu, (root,v) + tuple(v_list))
v_optionmenu.grid(column=4,row=11,sticky=(W,E))

var = v

root.bind('<Enter>',refresh_widget)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this code is incomplete and more importantly does not follow the same lib naming of the previous example. Please mind that often people come here looking for answers and, for this, coherence is a great thing.

Answer (score 4):

The piece you seem to be missing is that you can change the state with the `configure` method. Also, you can set a trace on a variable to have a function called when the value changes. Since you said you want to change the state based on a combobox, that is the technique you would use. You can do a similar trick with a radiobutton, though radiobuttons also have a `command` option which can be used instead of a trace.

Here's an example showing how to trigger a "refresh" function when a combobox changes:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.choiceVar = tk.StringVar()

        self.e1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.e2 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.cb = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=self.choiceVar,
                               values=["Enable 1 only", "Enable 2 only"])
        self.cb.set(self.cb.cget("values")[0])

        self.cb.pack(side="top")
        self.e1.pack(side="top")
        self.e2.pack(side="top")

        self.choiceVar.trace("w", self.on_trace_choice)
        self.refresh()

    def on_trace_choice(self, name, index, mode):
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        choice = self.cb.get()
        if choice == "Enable 1 only":
            self.e1.configure(state="normal")
            self.e2.configure(state="disabled")
        else:
            self.e1.configure(state="disabled")
            self.e2.configure(state="normal")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Fortunately I came up with an answer over the weekend. 
Your code is still useful to me as it will help me make the process more genric.
I would like to thank you for your effort :)